# Using .push stops for loop from executing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a for loop that suddenly stops working when I try to push to an array. The best way to describe what's going on is just to show my code and try an explain what's going on.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
  if (childs[i].length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < amountsValue[i].options.custValues.length; j++) {
      var label = amountsValue[i].options.custValues[j].label;
      var value = amountsValue[i].options.custValues[j].value;

      for (var k = childs[i].length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (childs[i][k].attributes[label] != value) {
          childBackup.push(childs[i][k]);
          childs[i].splice(k, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    amountsValue[i].id = childs[i][0].attributes.internalid;
    childs.push(childBackup);
  }
}
```

What's happening is I am looping through an array of items which may or may not have custom options available such as different sizes or colours. The loop will check to see if there are any then get the value and label from the array.

After this, we then loop again to try and match up the values with option values stored within a separate model. The plan is to check if the value is the same as the one stored and if not then splice it from the array. The process of elimination should eventually leave only one option left and that will be used to get the internalid.

During this a back up of the spliced objects is kept so that they can be appended to the array again so that the user can change the option they want. The problem is using childs.push(childBackup) stops the browser form reading the options on amountsValue. This works if the code is removed or it is pushed into another index so I'm really not sure why it isn't working.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working? I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense, I've tried to explain it as best I can but let me know if anything needs to be cleared up.

EDIT: I have fixed the issue. Thank you to everyone who suggested ways to solve the problem. As others said, I was trying to manipulate the array I was looping through and changing the length on it. So that part of the code was taken outside the loop and after the initial loop another loop was set up which contained the following code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < childBackup.length; i++) {
  childs[0].push(childBackup[i]);
}
```

It now works as intended. Thank you.

Comment: With every `.push()` you're changing the length of `childs`

Comment: please provide a working example

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with backbone. Please don't use unnecessary tags

Comment: Sorry T J, I am getting the data for childs from a Backbone model so I wasn't sure if I should include it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the array you are looping through.

```
var count = childs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  if (childs[i].length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < amountsValue[i].options.custValues.length; j++) {
      var label = amountsValue[i].options.custValues[j].label;
      var value = amountsValue[i].options.custValues[j].value;

      for (var k = childs[i].length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        if (childs[i][k].attributes[label] != value) {
          childBackup.push(childs[i][k]);
          childs[i].splice(k, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    amountsValue[i].id = childs[i][0].attributes.internalid;
    childs.push(childBackup);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why cloning the array? Just store the length of the array in a variable and use this variable instead of the `.length` property

Comment: JSON.parse doesn't seem to copy the structure correctly. In the original structure you'd have something like childs[i][k].attributes.internalid. However, in the copy it completely omits the attributes part so it doesn't loop correctly the second time.

Comment: See update, as noted copy isnt used and therefore redundant, the count is all that is needed.